# Trying to understand Context and its use in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I am using The Big Nerd Ranch Guide Android Programming. I completed the CriminalIntent project.

This is a method sequence being followed:

`CrimeLab.get(getActivity())`

`get` is a static method in `CrimeLab` class. It returns an instance of the `CrimeLab` class.

This is the `get` method:

```
public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
    if(sCrimeLab == null) {
        sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
    }
    return sCrimeLab;
```

This is the CrimeLab constructor:

```
private CrimeLab(Context context) {
    //mContext is a Context instance
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    //mDatabase is a SQLiteDatabase instance
    mDatabase = new CrimeBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
}
```

The CrimeBaseHelper (extends SQLiteOpenHelper) constructor:

```
public CrimeBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}
```

So, the Activity obtained in the `getActivity()` is ultimately passed to the constructor to the CrimeBaseHelper to create a SQLiteOpenHelper instance.

What I'm trying to understand is... what does the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor do with the Activity passed as Context?

What else could be passed as a Context to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Context allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
more details : [Context ? What Context ?](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)